# I am unable to access Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I have just created one of about view in `view/about.blade.php`, and I am accessing this from *localhost/myproject/public/about*, but it's not working.

However, localhost/myprojects/public/ is working fine; about view has been created on same parameters as welcome by default in Laravel.

Comment: have you created a route for about ?

Comment: 1: show route code, 2: show controller (code). without code we can't identify the issue

Comment: Please Show the route and Controller code

Comment: Start by reading the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7. If you have, you would know you are not supposed to create a page like `localhost/myproject/public/about`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the information is not sufficient to say anything.Please provide your route.Also its important how you are running your project ,is it via Xampp(or Lampp whatever is there) or "php artisan serve"
but looking from your working directory "localhost/myprojects/public" I guess its not by the command . Try **localhost/myprojects/public/about.blade.php** or run it by **php artisan serve** and try route **localhost:8000/about**

Comment: <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});

?>

Comment: You rock dear bro

Comment: One more suggestion if you like start using **php artisan serve** it will save you lot of trouble.Since it has in build server use Xampp only for mysql if you are habitual to use phpMyAdmin. I personally like workbench for DB and command to run on server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added particular routing to web.php file?

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Answer (score 0):

Which error are you getting?

404 - Not found

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

Check routes

`php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is a MVC Framework, Which means You Have a Controller which procede some logic when some request come in and interact with the model if need, after that the controller return some view.

And because you whan to acccess your view file, you must past through controller, and that controller will render the view. Because the views folder is not in the `\public` dicretory as subdirectory you can't access to It with url like `localhost/myproject/public/about` even if you get access to it, you will not get HTML, you'll get some plain text with **Blade tags**. It's a must to return view in you controller by rendering it, somewhere in the background Laravel procede all Blade Tag and return HTML that correspond to that tags.

What I can suggest you Is to create some route in your route file like this

```
Route::get('/about', function(Request $request){
    // Automatically Laravel will look this file in the view directory
    return view('about');
});
```

Or you can go with the controller like procedure by creating some controller, go in your terminal and execute

`php artisan make:controller AboutController`

this will generate a file name AboutController.php in `app\Http\Controllers` diretory within witch you will found

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

}
```

after that add

```
public function index()
{

    return View::make('about');
}
```

Don't forget to include `use the Illuminale\Supports\Facades\View` on top of your file

And one more important thing which left is to configure the **Route**, for that go in `routes` directory in the `web.php` file add

```
Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index')->name('about');
```

Comment: thank you your such a nice explanation bro, manish answer worked perfectly fine